# What is wrong with my header files?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I've just completed a school assignment and I'm having a problem testing my code because I keep getting the following output after running `make packetize` (it's a makefile the professor gave us)

```
cc     packetize.c   -o packetize
/tmp/ccJJyqF6.o: In function `block_to_packet':
packetize.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `crc_message'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [packetize] Error 1
```

`block_to_packet` is defined in a file called `packetize.c`, `crc_message` is defined in `crc16.c` (both of which contain an `#include "data.h"` line). `data.h` also has the function heading for `crc_message` in it All of these files are in the same directory. I've been trying to compile them for the past hour and a half and have searched Google endlessly with no avail. It has something to do with linking I've read, my instructor has not taught this and so I don't know how to compile these files to test their outputs. Can anyone let me know what's wrong?

Comment: The binary you're compiling (actually compiling and linking) should include code from both packetize.c and crc16.c. The simplest way to do this is to compile .c files separately and then link them into a single binary. Use `cc -c packetize.c -o packetize.o; cc -c crc16.c -o crc16.o; cc -o packetize packetize.o crc16.o`.

Comment: This command works well because it got rid of that single undefined function error, the issue now is that I have four more undefined function errors for functions which are defined within `data.h` and are used in `packetize.c`, I'm unsure how I would fix them if they're defined within `data.h`?

Comment: @Karysto: You are missing the point. "Undefined reference" is a *linker* error. Your compilation works correctly, your header files are (most likely) correct. You haven't understood yet that this is a two-step process: Compiling (to object code), and linking (to executable or library). You can *compile* a source file in isolation (.c >> .o), but then you have to *link* the resulting object files to get actually runable code. It's the *linker* complaining about something missing. You *really* have to understand what is happening there or you will keep running into problems over and over again.

Comment: I screened that post, it makes things easier to understand. I just really don't understand what the linker is complaining about. I'll try your code again.

Comment: @Karysto: Modern compilers integrate the linker, which is why you can get an executable out of the compiler directly. But originally, you needed to do `cc -c packetize.c -o packetize.o` (using the compiler), and *then* `ld packetize.o -o packetize` (using the linker). Again, the compiler could work on "incomplete" sources, leaving unresolved references (functions mentioned in headers but not defined anywhere the compiler could see). The *linker* "links" the references of 1..n object files together (hence the name). "Unresolved reference" is *always* an object file missing in the linker call.

Comment: You really know your stuff! The first line you wrote above worked and compiled, the second line with the linker is now saying that I'm using an implicit reference to `perror` in my code (many times). I have functions in `data.h` which use `perror` and are called in `packetize.c`.  This is one of the many lines being output after running the linker code above: `packetize.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to perror'
packetize.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to exit'`

Comment: @Karysto: I extended my answer with some elaboration on what a linker does. The functions `perror()` and `exit()` are defined in the standard C library, which is linked by default -- unless you took my `ld` line rather too literally, or are working with some non-standard setup (e.g. a crosscompiler). I was trying to make the difference between compiler and linker clear, not recommend calling `ld` directly. Going through `cc` is the smarter choice. (Thanks for the compliment; I should hope I know my stuff, I did this for a living the last 15 years...)

Comment: I did take it literally, I'm quite desparate lol I'll definitely read over your answer and make the best of it. Thanks for all the help, you really know how to explain things as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header files are absolutely OK. What you have there is a *linker* error: The compilation of `packetize.c` ran without problems, but then you're trying to link an *executable* file `packetize` (since you did not give the `-c` option which states "compile to *object* file"). And the executable would need the compiled code from `crc16.c` as well.

Either you have to give all sources on the compiler line:

```
cc packetize.c crc16.c -o myApp
```

Or you have to compile into individual object files, eventually linked together:

```
cc -c packetize.c -o packetize.o
cc -c crc16.c -o crc16.o
cc packetize.o crc16.o -o myApp
```

The former is what you'd do in a one-shot command line, the latter is what a Makefile usually does. (Because you do not need to recompile `crc16.c` if all you did was modify `packetize.c`. In large projects, recompiles can take significant amounts of time.)

**Edit:**

Tutorial time. Take note of the existence / absence of `-c` options in the command lines given.

Consider:

```
// foo.c

int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

A source file *defining* the function `foo()`.

```
// foo.h

int foo();
```

A header file *declaring* the function `foo()`.

```
// main.c

#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

A source file *referencing* `foo()`.

In the file `main.c`, the include makes the compiler aware that, eventually, somewhere, there will be a definition of the function `foo()` declared in `foo.h`. All the compiler needs to know at this point is that the function will exist, that it takes no arguments, and that it returns `int`. That is enough to *compile* the source to object code:

```
cc -c main.c -o main.o
```

However, it is **not** enough to actually compile an executable:

```
cc main.c -o testproc   # fail of compile-source-to-exe
ld main.o -o testproc   # fail of link-object-to-exe
```

The compiler was promised (by the declaration) that a definition of `foo()` will exist, and that was enough *for the compiler*.

The **linker** however (implicitly run by `cc` in the first example) *needs* that definition. The executable needs to *execute* the function `foo()`, but it is nowhere to be found in `main.c`. The reference to `foo()` cannot be resolved. "Unresolved reference error".

You need to either compile *both* source files in one go...

```
cc foo.c main.c -o testproc    # compile-source-to-exe
```

...or compile `foo.c` as well and provide the linker with *both* object files so it can resolve all references:

```
cc -c foo.c -o foo.o
ld foo.o main.o -o testproc    # link-objects-to-exe
```

**Post Scriptum**: Calling `ld` directly as pictured above most likely will not work just like that. Linking needs a couple of additional parameters, which `cc` adds implicitly -- the C runtime support, the standard C library, stuff like that. I did not give those parameters in the examples above as they would confuse the matter and are beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile crc16.c as well and link these two object files to build the binary. Otherwise packetize.c, from where crc_message() is being called, has no knowledge of it.

Try using

`cc packetize.c crc16.c -o packetize`

Your call crc_message() from packetize.c would just be fine.

Comment: I compiled `crc16.c` using this command and now have undefined function errors for other functions defined in `data.h`, would you know how to get rid of those?

Comment: This usually means that source files containing those functions are not being compiled. So what you is do is to provide all the necessary files in cc and compile and link them all. cc <list-of-all-files> -o packetize

Answer (score 0):

As Totland writes crc_message is defined in crc16.c; which means that packetize.c can't see the definition, no matter how many shared headers they have. You do not have a compile error but an error from the linker.

If you compile your c files first to object files and then link everything to an executable it will work.